# H-Closed Space has a unique weaker topology which is Minimal Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Problem 17M of Willard is -

> Every H-closed space has a unique weaker topology which is minimal Hausdorff. 
> (Hint: Use complements of regularly closed sets in $X$ as a base for a new topology)

I've been able to use the hint to construct a new topology, and have shown that it is a Hausdorff space. However, I've not been able to show that it is minimal Hausdorff, and that such a minimal Hausdorff space is unique. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The complements of regular closed sets are the regular open sets. So the new topology is the so-called semi-regularisation of $X$. A semiregular $H$-minimal space is $H$-closed(within $T_2$ spaces), showing minimality.

Comment: How do we show that the semi-regularization preserves minimal Hausdorff-ness? That's the main step I'm stuck in

Comment: No, the issue is preserving $H$-closedness.

Comment: How do we show that then?

Comment: Also, are you using the result '$X$ is minimal Hausdorff iff it is H-closed and semiregular?' If so, then I don't think Willard intends this to be used for this problem, as proving '$X$ is minimal Hausdorff iff it is H-closed and semiregular' is the next part of the problem.

Comment: If we have an open filter in the coarser topology, it has a cluster point in the original topology, which is also a cluster point in the coarser one. QED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basic facts: Let $X$ be Hausdorff, then $X$ is $H$-closed iff every open filter on $X$ has a clusterpoint, and $X$ is $H$-minimal iff it is $H$-closed and semiregular (=the regular open sets form a base).

If $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is $H$-closed, and $\mathcal{T}'\subseteq \mathcal{T}$ is a Hausdorff topology, then $(X, \mathcal{T}')$ is $H$-closed (clear from the open ultrafilter characterisation). So the semiregularisation of $\mathcal{T}$ (which we can take as such a $\mathcal{T}'$, which is the topology suggested by Willard, is a Hausdorff seniregular and $H$-closed topology and hence $H$-minimal by known results.

So if $\mathcal{T}'$ is a $H$-minimal and coarser than $\mathcal{T}$ then we know it's $H$-closed and semiregular, and so it must be equal to the semiregularisation of $(X, \mathcal{T})$, showing unicity.

Comment: I don't think Willard intended using '$X$ is $H$-minimal iff it is $H$-closed and semiregular' to prove this, as this is the next part of the question

Comment: @IshanDeo Then follow Porter and Grant Woods' exposition in 4.8 (section on $H$-closed) and 7.5 (on $H$-minimal spaces) of *Extensions and Absolutes of Hausdorff spaces* , which you should have on your shelf anyway if you're into these subjects. Also 2.2 on semiregular spaces. A very thorough book on all of this.

Comment: I had just found that myself! From just a cursory glance, it looks like a wonderful book!

Comment: @IshanDeo Hans Vermeer (a Dutch topologist I used to know) contributed to that book, and did his thesis on these kinds of spaces as well.